# How To Fix AWS EBS Storage Issue With Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I have an Ubuntu server in AWS. It runs a WordPress multi site, which has worked perfectly for some years. However now the site is constantly crashing as a result of lack of or no space.

To restore the site I have delete at least 1 plugin. However the no space issue quickly returns and the site crashes. I have also deleted about 8GB of log files, yet in a matter of hours same issue. No Space.

Running the following command.

```
df -hT /dev/xvda1
```

Shows that there is enough space available, as shown below.

```
Filesystem Type Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1     ext4   59G   26G   31G  46% /
```

Runging the following comand

```
df -h
```

Have the following results

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            996M   12K  996M   1% /dev
tmpfs           201M  396K  200M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1       59G   26G   31G  46% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          1001M     0 1001M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

How can I narrow down the cause of this issue and fix it?

Comment: Do you have any volumes reported by `df` other than `xvda`?  How big is your log directory: `sudo du -ms /var/log`?

Comment: To my knowledge only only 1 volume. If there is a way to check please let me know I ran your command and returned "83   /var/log" not sure what it means

Comment: That shows 83 MB total in /var/log, which is not much.  The command `df -h` will show all volumes - can you post the output of that?  Also what is the error message you're getting from WordPress?

Comment: Generates a white screen, and error log shows wordfrence can't find space to write it files. Note: Now I can't even create an empty directory via FTP. I get the no space error